# Spring upload file size limit

Tags: spring, file, upload, size, max

I'm using Spring Boot for my application, and I want to upload some files into my database.
I used a tutorial to achive this, and it works fine. My problem is that I don't know how to set max file size to upload. The default is 1MB but that's just not enough for me.

I added these lines to my `application.properties`:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size = 100MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size = 100MB
```

but it didn't help.

My code:

**FileService.java**

```
@Service
public class FileService {
@Autowired
FileRepository fileRepository;
public Response uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws  IOException {
    
    Response response = new Response();
    List fileList = new ArrayList();
    
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String uploadedFile = itr.next();
        MultipartFile file = request.getFile(uploadedFile);
        String mimeType = file.getContentType();
        String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        File newFile = new File(filename, bytes, mimeType);
        File savedFile = fileRepository.saveAndFlush(newFile);
        savedFile.setFile(null);
        fileList.add(savedFile);
    }
    
    response.setReport(fileList);
    return response;
}
}
```

**FileController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {
            
    @Autowired
    FileService fileService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
        return fileService.uploadFile(request);
     }
}
```

This code is just fine, it works perfectly, I just can't set max file size.

Comment: properties looks fine, Are you getting any error when you try with bigger file?

Comment: MultipartException

Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field uploadfile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using.

Comment: I used 1.3. The names of the properties are changed, these were multipart.maxFileSize and multipart.maxRequestSize. After I switched to Spring Boot 1.4 the properties above worked fine.

Comment: List of spring properties:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.servlet.multipart.enabled

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With Spring earlier than 4.0 the right properties are

**multipart.maxFileSize**

**multipart.maxRequestSize**

From Spring 4 these were changed to

**spring.http.multipart.max-file-size**

**spring.http.multipart.max-request-size**

Answer (score 16):

This configuration worked for me:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Reference to docs: [Tuning File Upload Limits](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#_tuning_file_upload_limits)

Answer (score 13):

For me worked (in Spring Boot 2.0.0):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
```

Comment: Negative value mean that this restriction is disabled at all. You can do it so but in this case you have to control incoming traffic on front. Negative value is an open door for DDoS.